# How to union two dataframes which have same number of columns?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

Dataframe df1 contains columns : a, b, c, d, e (Empty dataframe)

Dataframe df2 contains columns : b, c, d, e, _c4 (Contains Data)

I want to do a union on these two dataframes. I tried using

```
df1.union(df2);
```

This populates data with position. but i want to populated data with name of the columns.

Then I tried with

```
df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns= true);
```

But it throws the error in ``allowMissingColumns= true`. I get to know the error this is because of the version. I use spark version 2.4.4.

df1:

```
|a|b|c|d|e|
+---------+
| | | | | | 
+---------+
```

df2:

```
|b|c|d|e|_c4|
+-----------+
|2|3|5|6|   | 
+-----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
|a|b|c|d|e|
+---------+
| |2|3|5|6| 
+---------+
```

My question is there any other way to override an empty dataframe (df1) with populated dataframe (df2) using the column names? or should i need to change the version in pom.xml file?
Kindly pour some suggestions.

Pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>rule</groupId>
  <artifactId>qwerty</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>qwerty</name>
  <description>code</description>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>qwerty.qwerty</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <source>1.8</source> <target>1.8</target> </configuration> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unionByName` exists since spark `2.3` but the `allowMissingColumns` only appeared in spark `3.1`, hence the error you obtain in `2.4`.

In spark `2.4`, you could try to implement the same behavior yourself. That is, transforming `df2` so that it contains all the columns from `df1`. If a column is not in `df2`, we can set it to null. In scala, you could do it this way:

```scala
val df2_as1 = df2
    .select(df1
        .columns
        .map(c => if(df2.columns.contains(c)) col(c) else lit(null).as(c))
    : _*)
// Here, union would work just as well.
val result = df1.unionByName(df2_as1)
```

In java, that's obviously much more painful:

```java
List<String> df2_cols = Arrays.asList(df2.columns());
// cols is the list of columns contained in df1, but all columns
// that are not in df2 are set to null.
List<Column> cols = new ArrayList<>();
for (String c : df1.columns()) {
    if(df2_cols.contains(c))
          cols.add(functions.col(c));
    else
          cols.add(functions.lit(null).alias(c));
}
// We modify df2 so that its schema matches df1's.
Dataset<Row> df2_as1 = df2.select(JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(cols).toSeq());
        
// Here, union would work just as well.
Dataset<Row> result = df1.unionByName(df2_as1);
```

Comment: That helps ! but i couldn't implement the same in java. If possible can you change the syntax to java in the code.

Comment: I edited the answer with a java version ;-)

Comment: In this line of code Dataset<Row> df2_as1 = df2.select(JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(cols).toSeq()); I've used JavaConvesions and haven't used toSeq() but the code works fine for me..is there any catch on this?

Comment: Honestly I am not a great expert of java/scala conversions. I mostly code in scala but I would say that as long as the way you convert your list and feed it to spark compiles, it should work as expected.